# What will happen to the files inside the Windows Installer if I choose to keep nothing during installation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade, windows-installation

Assuming I wanted to upgrade my System from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

I have the installer extracted from another drive disk and my files are in single directory including the Windows Installer.

e.g. of file structure:

- MY_BACKUP (Here is my files)
- boot
- support
- autorun.inf
- bootmgr.efi
- setup.exe

during selection on which file to keep, I choose `Nothing` and I continue to upgrade my system.

is my file safe? as far as I know the drive where the installer will not be affected but I'm not so sure about it.

Comment: I also thought that the files where the Windows Installer won't be affected during the upgrade, I hope someone clarify it.

Comment: If you choose nothing, your personal files will be deleted, since your current installation will be wiped.  The only files that will be migrated are those personal files in your user profile directory.  Files outside of your user profile shouldn't be touched, but if you cannot lose them, you should back them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, your backup file(s) will be safe.**

Usually, Windows Installer will extract any necessary installation files to a (hidden) temporary directory and delete them upon installation.

In any case, Windows Installer will only remove the files it extracted/used for installation and not any others (such as your backup files).